# React Docker App Implementation for a client base production

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile, environment-variables, docker-desktop

Docker is already initilized in my application, I want to pass an Environment variable from Docker Desktop and want to set that variable value in my React App ENV for client side deployment.

Can anyone please guide me for that?

Tried every prospective from CHAT-GPT, Google and with Youtube references but it's failing
[image]